# Domain name never return requested path/document, only /index.html

Tags: domains, web-hosting, dns

I have my own web server and I purchased domain name to use it with my website.

For example - my domain name is `www.example.com`

When I navigate to `www.example.com/example.html` (or `www.example.com/example`) I will always be redirected to `178.xx.xx.xx/index.html`.

I was able to implement navigation within my website using relative links, but when I do so it would not show the correct URL (for example, I am on `www.example.com/index.html` page, and I navigate to `/example.html` - URL bar would show `www.example.com/index.html` instead of `www.example.com/example.html`)

If I navigate to `178.xx.xx.xx/example.html` manually, it opens the right page, so I assume that my server works correctly.

I am using Debian with Apache for my web server. 
For my domain I redirect `www.example.com` to `http://178.xx.xx.xx/` with cloak.

From all above I assume the problem is with my domain configuration, as I tried my friend domain name, and it worked correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have a basic A Host setup with your domain registrar host. If its correct then edit your htaccess and make sure that looks fine

Comment: Thanks. My problem was, I had Web Forward enabled instead of A Record.